# What determine the length of encrypted String in RSA?

Tags: iphone, encryption, rsa

I know about length of some small encrypted strings as: 160, 196 ..

What determines the size?

Comment: [Block padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Padding)?

Comment: Generally, the length of an encrypted string is the length of the plaintext string, rounded up to a "block" boundary.

Comment: in my project android, it is alway to be 160 length but in my iphone project it always 196 length. thanks for your answer

Comment: @ Hot Licks: my modulus string length :289, and exponent: 65537 but i don't know how to make any text to be 180 crypted string length any suggestion for me.

Comment: which encryption algorithm are you using? DES,AES ..etc??

Comment: @ Pratyusha Terli: i implement the RSA encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size in bytes of a single "block" encrypted is the same as the key size, which is the same as the size of the modulus. The private exponent is normally about the same size, but *may be smaller*. The public exponent can be up to to the key size in size, but is normally much smaller to allow for more efficient encryption or verification. Most of the time it is the fourth number of Fermat, 65537.

Note that this is the size in bits of the encrypted data. The plain data *must* be padded. PKCS#1 v1.5 uses at most the key size - 11 bytes padding for the plain text. It is certainly smart to keep a higher margin though, say 19 bytes padding minimum (a 16 byte random instead of a 8 byte random for padding).

For this reason, and because it is expensive to perform RSA encryption/decryption, RSA is mostly used in combination with a symmetric primitive such as AES - in the case of AES a random AES symmetric secret key is encrypted instead of the plain text. That key is then used to encrypt the plain text.

Comment: You are welcome Ngo Ky. if you think it answers your question, then don't forget to hit accept (the V mark next to the answer).